# How to clear IconCache in windows7 via NSIS

Tags: windows-7, caching, icons, nsis

I have a problem with installing of my application via NSIS in windows 7.
Application installs successfully, but instead of myApplicationsIcon windows shows generic icon.
I know how to fix this problem manually(delete IconCache.db in AppData\Local), but how can I do this with NSIS-script?

Regards, Dmitry.

Comment: Is this for the exe itself? or for shortcuts to the exe? (i.e. start menu and desktop)  It does make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try calling [SHChangeNotify](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Refresh_shell_icons) first?

If that is not enough, use the delete instruction and the $localappdata constant

Answer (score 0):

If your exe file is extremely large, Windows will sometimes not display the icon.